# Toilet bowl overfills before flushing, then stays drained

Tags: toilet

Toilet bowl is filling almost all the way up when flushed, then flushes fast and stays almost empty. I put dawn in it and poured hot water into it. I read to fill it up with hot water to the rim and then flush. Before pouring all the water in, it flushed on its own. I poured more hot water in and it did it again. All are fast flushes. The refill stage still leaves the bowl almost empty.

Comment: I would not put any more hot water in the toilet because you could damage the wax ring seal. Have you tried a plunger? Push moderately and pull vigorously. You might have a blockage in a vent.

Comment: I did prior to the hot water... hadn't thought to try it again after. Will do. thanks Jim! (and for the hot water/wax ring seal info too)

Comment: I am not really competent to diagnose this toilet draining problem because I don't understand in detail the elements of design of drains in houses, but to hazard a guess, if water is being sucked out of the trap built into a toilet I would think that is due to a vent being plugged so that the movement of the slug of water in the drain after flushing  is not able to pull air through a vent. This makes a vacuum which pulls the water out of the trap in the toilet bowl. You might try flushing the toilet and then using the plunger near the end of the flush to pull back on the vent.

Comment: It is not clear to me if the vent for a toilet is supposed to be upstream or downstream of where the toilet connects into the drains.

Comment: Sounds like the refill tube (which slowly runs water into the bowl while the tank is refilling) isn't working.

Comment: @Daniel Griscom 's idea is a good one. There is supposed to be a plastic tube feeding into the overflow tube to fill the bowl. Sometimes these get displaced so water is no longer going in. If you would rapidly pour 1.6 gal (from a bucket) into a perfectly functioning toilet, it would flush but the momentum of the water flow would pull nearly all the water out with the result of an improperly low level in the bowl (so no water seal). To restore the water seal you would then have to pour an additional smaller amount water into the bowl slowly enough so that you do not start the (siphon) flush.

Answer (score 1):

The flushing action appears to be working normally. A toilet flushes because the water level reaches the vertical level inside the covered portion of the bowl.

The refill portion is possibly because the tube that is inside the tank has become dislodged. Remove the cover and look for a small diameter tube, perhaps pencil diameter that now has a loose end. There will also be a larger diameter vertical tube to which this smaller tube attaches. The clip will be on either tube and they should be joined to allow the flow from the smaller tube to reach the bowl, completing the refill.

From https://www.handymanhowto.com/how-to-replace-a-toilet-fill-valve-part-4/
[image: refill tube]